# Why Flutter expansion card has border up and down?

Tags: flutter

I have this sample app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
void main() => runApp(const CardExampleApp());

class CardExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Card Sample')),
        body: const CardExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CardExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: makeCard(),
    );
  }
Card makeCard() => Card(
      child: Container(
        child: makeExpansionTile(),
      ));
  
ExpansionTile makeExpansionTile() =>
      ExpansionTile(
        title: const Text("Title"),
         children: <Widget>[new Text("content")],
      );
}
```

Why the open expansion card has a border up and down? How can I eliminate it?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `InputBorder.none`

```dart
ExpansionTile(
  shape: InputBorder.none,
  title: const Text("Title"),
  children: <Widget>[new Text("content")],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options use can try.

1. Use Colors.transparent with width = 0;

   `shape: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0),`
2. Use this border none option.

   `shape: InputBorder.none,`

Full code of the widget example.

```
ExpansionTile(
              shape: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0),
              title: const Text('ExpansionTile with implicit controller.'),
              children: <Widget>[
                Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Collapse This Tile'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          return ExpansionTileController.of(context).collapse();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
```